# iOS14 - How to change textColor of UIDatePicker in UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit, uidatepicker, ios14

Using iOS14.0.1, Swift5.3, Xcode12.0.1,

I try to change the `textColor` of a `UIDatePicker` in iOS14 and using UIKit.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820746/uidatepicker-crash-on-ios-14-while-setting-textcolor-via-kvc) that you need the following method to do so:

```swift
let myDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
myDatePicker.tintColor = .white
```

---

I also tried the following (but that makes my app crash under iOS14):

```swift
myDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

---

I also tried (but without success either):

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self]).textColor = UIColor.white
```

---

In light mode, none of my trials work (as can bee seen in the screenshot-excerpt):

[image]

What do I need to do to get the white color text in my `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: If you have a use case for this feature, please file an enhancement request with Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, add the extension below:

```
extension UIDatePicker {

var textColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    }
    get {
        return value(forKeyPath: "textColor") as? UIColor
    }
  }
}
```

Now in viewDidLoad call:

```
myDatePicker.textColor = .yourColor
```

call it after other picker property, es.:

```
myDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
myDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
myDatePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
myDatePicker.backgroundColor = .black
myDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
myDatePicker.textColor = .yourColor // here
```

[image]

if you want highlightsToday set the relative picker value to true:

```
myDatePicker.setValue(true, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fabio - I did not have time to test your solution yet. Are you sure it will work in iOS14 since `forKeyPath: "textColor"` does not seem to work anymore in iOS14. Or is it still possible with your own extension implementation ?

Comment: @iKK Hi, I run it on Xcode 12 - iOS 14... And it works like a charme

Comment: in my case, it doesn't work in iOS 14. Did anybody find a solution? myDatePicker.setValue(true, forKey: "highlightsToday") crashes in iOS 14

Comment: crashing on ios 14.0

Comment: @AiyubMunshi simply call value key after you declare myDatePicker background color... No crash now, I update my answer, thanks for the alert!!!

Comment: What I was looking for `myDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")`

Comment: not working for iOS 16 beta

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It works! However, the proprety `preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels` must be set before `textColor = .yourColor`, or the propetty `textColor` may never be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I change picker view color using `pickerView delegate` method. You can add this function with add these delegate methods: `UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource`

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

      // change your picker view textColor etc. in here..
}
```

Comment: thank you mehmett - I will try this solution as well....